# MSVCP100.dll system error and can't connect to my wifi

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

when I start my laptop there is a system error that says "This program can't start because MSVCP100.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this program" and I think this system error is preventing my wifi from connecting, other device connects fine. Please help. My laptop is Toshiba Satellite L655.

Answer (score 3):

The MSVCP100.dll is part of the Visual C++ 2010 Runtime. Download the correct runtime and install it.

32Bit:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328

64Bit:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13523

Answer (score -1):

U can also load it from here http://fix4dll.com/msvcp100_dll . But don't forget to choose the correct Windows version (32 or 64bit).

Comment: **DO NOT** download the file linked by this author. The website SHOULD NOT be trusted.  If you need the Visual C++ 2010 Runtime download it from Microsoft